# Why did Aleister create the Science Side?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Why did Aleister create the Science Side? Do we actually know?

From [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/ACertainMagicalIndexAcademyCityLeadership):

> **Reality Warper**: He is capable of omnipresence and other tricks. Confirmed when it is revealed at the end of New Testament volume 11 that he possesses something called the Archetype Controller, which can basically create or destroy Jungian archetypes, which would be like the equivalent of controlling tropes, in a way. It is revealed that, using this power, he literally created the entire concept of a "Science side", and made Academy City and its espers part of the archetype of "mankind’s worship of science".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of revelations from New Testament 19, yes we now know.

> Aleister's first daughter died after caching Typhoid fever. It wasn't anyone's fault, it was just a stroke of ill fortune. So, Aleister decided to *destroy all misfortune* - that is, destroy all magic and religion. That would remove all forms of coincidence from the world, and no one would ever be unfortunate again. (Though, as Touma points out, that would mean that no one would ever be *lucky* again either.)